# I am not able to capture SRN value in jmeter using regular exp extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter, performance-testing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6p1P.jpg)

Even though the value is present in the response, debug sampler is showing not found.
 I have already tried with cookie manager, authorization manager, header manager, deflate, bean shell pre processor.

Also the response assertion for that request is failing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpnMq.jpg)

Comment: Try (.*) instead (.*?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the XPath Extractor instead, will be easier, here is the XPath to use

//*[@name='SRN']/@value

Please make sure, you check the options, Use Tidy and Quiet in the XPath Extractor

[image]